# What is the optimal folder structure for a an enterprise Angular 16 project that helps with scalability and maintainability in a long term?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-cli, angular16

I'm about to start a fairly substantial Angular project that will implement several features and modules.

I'm currently uncertain about the optimal folder structure to choose in order to make the project highly scalable and easily maintainable in the long term.

I'm providing the following information that might help define the best project structure: This project will consist of approximately three modules. Two of these modules should each have about three features, while one should have around 15 features.

For my smaller projects, I've typically used the following structure:

```
└───src
    ├───app
    │   ├───modules
    │   │   ├───module1
    │   │   │   ├───components
    │   │   │   ├───models
    │   │   │   ├───services
    │   │   │   ├───helpers
    │   │   ├───module2
    │   │   │   ├───components
    │   │   │   ├───models
    │   │   │   ├───services
    │   │   │   ├───helpers
    │   │   ├───module3
    │   │   │   ├───components
    │   │   │   ├───models
    │   │   │   ├───services
    │   │   │   ├───helpers
    │   │   ├───...
    │   │   
    │   ├───shared
    │   │   ├───components
    │   │   ├───modules
    │   │   ├───interceptors
    │   │   ├───services
    │   │   ├───enums
    │   │   ├───...
```

I am considering whether to structure the folders by module, as I've done before. However, I've also come across suggestions to structure folders by feature. Given that my project could potentially have a significant number of features, I am unsure if I should opt for the second option or explore alternative solutions.

I would greatly appreciate your recommendations or suggestions!

Comment: This is very much a matter of opinion. I prefer my folder structure to match my mental model of the app. Separate reusable generic components, page-specific components, and top-level "controller" (or page) components. You should try to abstract behaviours where possible, but don't go overboard with inheritance. And be comfortable with the undeniable fact that Angular would be certain to impose a folder structure on you if they thought there was one single best approach.

Comment: There are, basically, three main ways to structure your app: the official (like you described), NX-way and a hybrid of both (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7SDpTOLeqHE) . The official way is a bit limited when it comes to larger modules, NX is a bit heavy because of extra tooling, hybrid is best for apps that start small and grow over time. The last two define not only features but also groups of features (aka areas in you app). From my experience, migration between those structures is not so complicated if you have clear boundaries between your modules and correctly setup aliases in tsconfig

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the interesting video. However, I have a question. Since you mentioned NX, in which case can we use the NX way? Do you recommend using NX in the above case, given that the project will use a code formatting library and Jest as the testing framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This video is very helpful regarding the topic of project architecture  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SaNO6ubhYyg

I think you can use the NX library even with a polyrepo. It helps a lot in organizing your folder structure.